# Corncob Pipe during Pesach

Tags: passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, tobacco-cig-smoking

Assuming smoking is permitted at all (thank you, Rav Moshe Feinstein) and that smoking on Yom Tov / Chol Ha'omed is also permitted in our times, could an Ashkenazi Jew holding by the kitniyot prohibition smoke a corncob pipe during Pesach? Smoking is clearly differentiated halachically from eating or drinking, and no corn flavor should make its way through the tobacco smoke....

Comment: This should be fine even for wheat. Wheat grain [when fermented]  is prohibited not the stalks

Comment: "thank you, Rav Moshe Feinstein" - Hashem should guard your being a fool.

Comment: We are all involved in one foolish behavior or another and luckily He guards over all of us, @DanF

Comment: @Josh he doesn't luckily guard all of us. we pray he guard after as many of us as possible.

Comment: Some pipe tobaccos are mixed with chametz or kitniyot, so it's not so pashut

Comment: Excellent point, @Noach. To be honest in my view one shouldn't smoke tobacco with any kind of additives year-round, but chas v'shalom a Jew should b'shogeg be exposed to chametz that way!